# Loop query result, and do something after every 100 records with overlap

Tags: php, mysql

**$result** contains a non specific amount of records.

I need to loop through $result, and after every 100 records, do something, and then continue the loop, but include 5 records from the previous loop (overlap).

Like this:

1. Get records 0-100
2. Do something with these records
3. Get records 95-195
4. Do something with these records
5. Get records 190-290

Anyone have a suggestion how this is done in the most efficient way?

Comment: I haven't written any code for this yet, since I'm unsure how to procede.

Comment: then please do write some code and ask again if you run into some trouble, in it's present form the question is far too broad.

Comment: Is stackoverflow only about fixing non-working code? Where can I ask about help making code?

Comment: Stackoverflow is about helping you with your efforts - not doing the work for you. There are plenty of books & online tutorials where you can find details of basic PHP & the various types of loop that can be performed. So the idea is you read up & try something, if it works then you have done well, otherwise present the code & people will most likely help you.

Comment: I didn't ask for someone to write the completed code for me, I asked for suggestions, pseudo-code or some way to get me started. In this case, just telling me that I should make a temprorary list etc. would be a lot of help since I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all I agree with the commentators. We are here to help with problems you've ran in, but not to write your script.

Neverthelesse I wrote a perlish solution of your problem:

```
$results; #your results

for($i = 0; $i <= @{$results}, $i++){ #loop through all results
    my @tempList;
    push(@tempList, @{$results}[$i]); #push every result in a temporary list
    if (@{$results} == 100 || $i == @{$results}) { #do sth, if the tempList hast 100 entries or you're at the last round of your loop
        #do sth with the 100 records
        $i -= 5; #decrement i to get the 5 entries overlap

    }
}
```

You can see that it's a simple loop through your results. Every 100th round the `if` will evaluate to true and you can do sth with your data.
The overlap is realised by decreasing the counter every 100th round. **Be careful** in the last round when finishing your loop! You will get an infinite loop if you don't escape the `$i -= 5;` in the last round!

Comment: Thank you! This looks like what I wanted! What's the purpose of the @? I thought it was only used for surpressing errors in functions?
Also, to check if it's final count, would I check if $i < $rowcount-5 ?

Comment: Like I said: It's perl. In Perl the `@` indicates an array and the `$` a scalar. In my example I used a reference (a pointer), a scalar, to the array of your results. Then I dereferenced it with the `@{$results}` get the array itself. In the for-loop it's a very perlish way to use the array in a scalar context to get it's length ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
    $slimit=0;
    $flimit=100;

    while($flimit<=total_records_in_your_table)
    {
        $q="select * from table_name limit $slimit,$flimit";

        while($data=mysql_fetch_row($q))
        {
            //opration
        }

        $slimit=$flimit-6;
        $flimit=$flimit+$slimit;

}
```

Comment: This was what I thought about first, but wouldn't it be much more to efficient to do this in PHP instead of making several queries?